# VideoView xamarin - endless video

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-videoview

I'm trying to code an application that loops a video indefinitely in an xamarin application.

I'm using a Odroid-X4U as device to connect to a TV to make a "SaverScreen" that play videos.

Here my code :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    session = new SessionManager(this);

    memoryTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewMemory);
    hourTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewHour);
    memoryTimer = new Timer(UpdateMemory, null, 0, 1000);

    videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
    videoView.Completion += VideoView_Completion;

    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

    PlayNextVideo();
}

private void PlayNextVideo()
{
    string tmpPath = App.AppMainFolder + "/" + videoUrls[1];
    videoView.SetVideoPath(tmpPath);
    videoView.Start();
}

private void VideoView_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    videoView.StopPlayback();
    videoView.Dispose();
    videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);

    hourTextView.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoUrls.Length;
    PlayNextVideo();
}
```

this code is functional, however after several hours the video freezes completely and I have to restart my device completely to restart the video.

I also put a little bloc of code to check the ram, and it's not a storage problem

```
private void UpdateMemory(object state)
{
    var memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    var activityManager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(ActivityService);
    activityManager.GetMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        memoryTextView.Text = "RAM : " + (memoryInfo.AvailMem / 1048576L) + "MB | time : " + currentTime;
    });
}
```

Does anyone have a solution so that the video doesn't freeze after a while?

I also went to the device logs (logcat) and nothing is displayed about the video bug.

Answer (score 1):

According to the native android case about [Seamless video Loop with VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746075/seamless-video-loop-with-videoview), you can try to loop the video with the `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` method.

First of all, declare the custom listener class:

```cs
public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnPreparedListener
{
    public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.Looping = true;
    }
}
```

And then set the listener for the videoview:

```
videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
videoView.SetOnPreparedListener(new MyListener());
```

Comment: Hello, thank you.

I'll come back to you tomorrow after testing it for 24 hours !

Comment: You are welcome. Looking forward to your feedback. @Arnaud

Comment: Unfortunately, the video still freezes after a few hours.

When I came back this morning, I didn't restart my device, only the application and the video were still frozen, so I'm checking the logs to see if there's something that was blocking the video, but i didn't find anything

i'm not used to stackoverflow, i don't know where i can send you this logs

Comment: Did you keep the code you used earlier? In addition, is there any limit on the TV such as the power saving mode? @Arnaud

Comment: Yes i keep the code, and no there is no power saving mode, because these devices are already use in the factory where i work and there are turn on 24h/24h with no probleme

Comment: All right, please try to delete the code you used earlier(such as the `PlayNextVideo()` and  `VideoView_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)` ) and only used the code I provided. @Arnaud

Comment: for my test yesterday, I just use one time PlayNextVideo(), i delete the VideoView_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e).

Comment: Sorry for I have no idea about this.

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help. I'Il get back to you if a find a solution